# Accessing array in a return method

Tags: java, arrays

Good evening people,

I have a method that creates, populates, and returns an array to the function call as so:

```
 public double[] getTotalDistances(){
  double[] distance;
   distance = new double[3];


    for(Activity r: diary ){

        if(r instanceof Run){
           distance[0] += r.getDistance(); 
        }
    }
   return distance;

}
```

and i can't seem to find a way to access this returned array to print it out in the main method, i have tried this: (where m is the object i have instantiated)

```
for(int i = 0; i< m.getTotalDistances().length; i++){

        System.out.println(m.getTotalDistances().distance[i]);
    }
```

this says it cannot find the variable distance.

i am aware that i can do something like:

```
 for(double i: m.getTotalDistances()){
      System.out.println(i);
}
```

this will print out the returned array, however, i would like to know how to do it in the "classic" way.I know that this must be extremely novice, but i couldn't find an answer. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `m.getTotalDistances()[i]` and not `m.getTotalDistances().distance[i]`

Comment: Oh i see, thank you, that works like a charm, there seems to be a minimum time to accept an answer so i will accept the answer in 8 minutes

Comment: This will calculate `getTotalDistances()` every time again in the loop and is prone to concurrency problems.

Answer (score 2):

Use a variable to store it before iterating.

```
double[] distance = m.getTotalDistances();
for(int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++){
        System.out.println(distance[i]);
}
```

Your approach would call your `getTotalDistances()` method over and over inside the loop. You only need it once to work with.

You get this error

> this says it cannot find the variable distance.

because the variable `distance` is only known in the scope of your method `getTotalDistances()` and thus you cannot use it outside of that (and it wouldn't make sense either).

Answer (score 1):

The way it is written, `distance` is not defined.  You will need to create a pointer the the returned value if you want to reference it.

```
double[] distance = getTotalDistances();
for(int i = 0; i < distance.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(distance[i]);
}
```

Also, as it is written, any values other than the first will always be 0, and an accumulator makes more sense.

Another thing to note is that, as it is written, `getTotalDistances()` will run twice on each iteration of your `for` loop; once for the condition and again for the `println()`.  If you were to scale this concept to a larger use case, the performance implications would be huge.